# Custom icon of status bar item in vscode extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, statusbaritem

The documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api says that icon-name can be taken from the octicon, is it possible to insert icon that is not an octicon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, at least, not yet.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10455) asking to support more icons, but no Milestone defined.

Comment: Now 2022 it is easy, see the sailendra dash's answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can add your custom icon.
https://glyphter.com/
add your 5 X 5 svg logo here in section A, then Download the font.

in vscode's package.json

```
"contributes": {
 "icons": {
        "custom-icon-id": {
            "description": "custom descr",
            "default": {
                "fontPath": "./customicon.woff", //woff file
                "fontCharacter": "\\41" //you added svg logo in section A
            }
        }}
```

Comment: Hi, I did this but the icon only shows itself as "A", any suggestions?

Comment: I know what fontCharacter should be: see "{content:'\0043';}" in the CSS file downloaded alongside the font folder.

Comment: @K.Symbol sorry for late reply, yes you are right I just replace character A to icon but you can only use this icon on status bar of vscode , after you create status bar item , there you can provide the text like `$(custom-icon-id) any text` the name should be exactly match to that id which you mentioned in package.json under contributes > icons